# Android ffmpeg lib has no runnable permission

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have an app that works with `ffmpeg` library. There are free and full version. Both version
works fine, but after upload them to google play and then install from it full version begin says `"java.io.IOException: Error running exec() Working Directory: null"` when I try to use `ffmpeg`. 
I root my device to check libraries (`libffmpeg.so`) in app folder and I found that in free version library has
`-rwxr-xr-x` permission that is normal but full version library has `-rw-r--r--` permission that is read only.
If I install app without google play from my `apk`'s all works fine.